# Wscript does not run .vbs script due to an excel message box which pops up during refresh process

Tags: vbscript, excel-2010

Task: I am currently working on an automation task via Windows Task Scheduler, so users can have a daily / weekly report.

Issue: I am running .vbs script, from a .bat file. The macro in the .vbs script refreshes all the pivot tables / slicers within the report and saves updated report, then it closes the Excel report application.

During testing I noticed that the .bat file stops at the point of running the refresh because Excel report comes up with the below msgBox message and then requires YES/NO in order to continue thereafter that another msg box asking to click YEs to replace the current file after refresh.
Below are the two msgbox that comes up in Excel:

> [image: Blockquote]
> [image: Blockquote]

Question: How do I write the .vbs script to automatically click yes to the msg boxes instead of doing it manually, there is no point of automation if there is any manual work needed. I need a clean smooth automation and I have tried to write the .vbs script in different ways.

the .vbs script below:

```vb
'Input Excel File's Full Path
'ExcelFilePath = ***Excel report file path
  
'Input Module/Macro name within the Excel File
  MacroPath = "RefreshReport"

'Create an instance of Excel
  Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

'Do you want this Excel instance to be visible?
  ExcelApp.Visible = True 'or "False"

'Prevent any App Launch Alerts (ie Update External Links)
  ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = False 'or "True"

'Open Excel File
  Set wb = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFilePath)

'Execute Macro Code
  ExcelApp.Run MacroPath

'Save Excel File (if applicable)
  wb.Save

'Reset Display Alerts Before Closing
  ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = True 'or "False"

'Close Excel File
  wb.Close

'End instance of Excel
  ExcelApp.Quit

'Leaves an onscreen message!
  'MsgBox "Your Automated Task successfully ran at " & TimeValue(Now), vbInformation
```

Comment: The `.bat` file is not stopping.  The `vbscript` is stopping.

Comment: Sounds like your macro needs to wait for processes to complete before saving.  If you hit `enter` to clear the message box, then your data won't be refreshed.

Comment: exactly does not refresh when i hit enter to clear the message box

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sending {Enter} in the script to accept the MsgBox?

```
set shell = createobject("wscript.shell")
shell.sendkeys ("{Enter}")
```

https://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html

Comment: Do I put this code at the beginning or the end in the vbs script?

Comment: I have tried to include the send key code but it did not work.

Comment: @YemisiAdeoluwa you would need to included this code in the Script where the MsgBox comes up, and may need to add a pause in the Script to wait for it, this code will send a key press of the Enter key, if the window is actually active this should allow it to accept the default option on the box.